# How to generate image Thumb minimal coding

Tags: asp.net, image, thumbnails

How to generate image as Thumb in simple way **i think minimal coding** on asp.net,
Then after how to save particular folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried like this so cool..!!,

```
 public void ThumbGenerate(string sourcepath,string thumbsavepath, int width, int height)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(sourcepath);
        Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
        thumb.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(thumbsavepath, "jpg"));
   }
```

***Note :You can change extension what you like something  jpg,jpeg,png***

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use the "Image.GetThumbnailImage" method because of the poor quality
(search "Image.GetThumbnailImage quality" on your favorite search engine...)

Here is a code snippet:

```
void GenerateThumbnail(string sourceImagePath, string destImagePath, int width, int height, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat destImageFormat)
{
    using (var destImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;                    
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            using (var sourceImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourceImagePath))
            {
                g.DrawImage(sourceImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
            }

            destImage.Save(destImagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

- OR - you can use Piczard ([Piczard](http://piczard.com/))

Here are some usage examples:

```
// 50% thumbnail (Jpeg image format)
var filter = new CodeCarvings.Piczard.ImageTransformation(50);
filter.SaveProcessedImageToFileSystem("~/MySourceImage.jpg", "~/MyDestImage.jpg");

// Fixed size thumbnail 400x200 (PNG image format)
var filter2 = new CodeCarvings.Piczard.FixedResizeConstraint(400, 200);
filter.SaveProcessedImageToFileSystem("~/MySourceImage2.jpg", "~/MyDestImage2.png");
```